# Login to IDM Server with Ubuntu Client

Tags: server, login, remote

I am new to Linux Admininstration and IDM server.

I am using CentOS 7 on one machine ( PC1) and Ubuntu Client on another machine (PC2) .
On the CentOS I have installed IDM Server which is running quite perfectly on the PC1.( i am able to login via browser )
I have configured and joined PC2 to PC1 IDM server via idm-client-install and added users to the IDM server.

When I login to my Ubuntu box ( PC2 ) I can successfully login to IDM server via SSH using terminal on the Ubuntu.
What I am failing at ( and really don't know if this would work or not ) is I can't see the IDM Domain Users names at the Login Screen @ my Ubuntu box.

In other words, I want to login to IDM server via Ubuntu Client from the GUI Login Screen. ( Just like an Active Directory Server User logs in from a windows client )

Is it possible ? If yes - what is the basic pre-requisite for this ?

Thanks & Regards,
Kaustubh